# How do I properly apply CSS to button elements?

Tags: html, css, button

all. Very new to HTML and CSS, and I'm having trouble applying CSS to some buttons. Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="top-buttons">
        <button id="first-button">One</button>
        <button id="second-button">Two</button>
        <button id="third-button">Three</button>
        <button id="fourth-button">Four</button>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  /* padding */
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* font-size */
  margin: 15px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #564946;
}

#first-button{
  border-radius: 20%;
}
```

I was toying around and was able to get only the `border-radius` to work; none of the other properties worked, even when I switched it from `.button` to `.top-buttons`. Any ideas? Only other thought I have at this point is it may be the text editor I'm using? I just stuck with Atom because I had previously installed it. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: you are styling the class `.button` not the elements `button` :)

Comment: What you are using there is a class selector, where you intend to use an element selector. For your journey through CSS I would suggest https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS and the book https://www.amazon.com/CSS-Definitive-Guide-Eric-Meyer/dp/0596527330

Comment: Thank you, everyone! Will definitely check out those resources and keep practicing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons are wrapped within `<button></button>` tags, whereas you are applying your styling to `.button` class, so if you want to apply global styling to those buttons, you should use following to apply styling to button tag:

```
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  /* padding */
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* font-size */
  margin: 15px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #564946;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need to specify the element that you what to affect.
For example, there are two ways to solve that

1. Styles only for the buttons inside .top-buttons:

```css
.top-buttons > button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #564946;
}
```

2. Styles for all buttons

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #564946;
}
```